# Contour plot of data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two vectors (plain lists), say `a,b`, from which I generated a 2d table, say `mat`. It's not a direct expression like `mat[[i,j]] = a[[i]] + b[[j]]`, rather some more complicated computation that spans much of my code, but each entry $ij$ is essentially just some function of the corresponding `a[[i]]` and `b[[j]]]`.

I'd like to plot that, perhaps as a contour plot, but I see that Mathematica expects the data to be given as a matrix where each entry $ij$ is a triplet `a1[[i]],a2[[j]],mat[[i,j]]`.

How do I construct this matrix of triplets in a proper Mathematica "way of thinking"? (i.e. without nested loops etc.) Or alternatively, can I use my current data structure and plot it directly?

Comment: See [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html), it doesn't make any difference how you generated your `mat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Table[{a[[i]],b[[j]],a[[i]]+b[[j]]},{i,1,ni},{j,1,nj}]
```